# Chrome hangs for 15s+, no clues in DevTools — how can I debug this?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

One page on a client's site causes Chrome to hang unresponsively for 15 seconds or so. On macOS, the browser locks up completely and the spinning wheel appears.

There are no issues whatsoever in Safari or Firefox. I have no idea why this is happening, and DevTools doesn't seem to give any clues as to what's causing it.

Here's a screenshot of the timeline — note the flurry of activity in the final second, when the browser becomes responsive after seemingly doing "nothing" in the latter half:

[image: chrome timeline]

Some comments on the timeline above:

- At ~12,500ms the page *looks ready*. In any other browser, it is ready for interaction at this point. You can see the final green chunk in the timeline finishes around here.
- Chrome completely locks up between 12,500ms and 28,500ms.
- I initially assumed the problem was with one of the 3rd-party/analytics scripts, as you can see the timeline shows activity from these right in the final second (> 28,000ms). I tried switching every one of these off, but exactly the same thing happens.
- This is a particularly large page, as it lists several thousand records in a JS datatable. I appreciate performance can be improved, but I don't believe that's the root cause. The page/plugin has been working absolutely fine for several years.

What can I try next? Thanks!

Comment: _"as it lists several thousand records in a JS datatable"_ Disable that table, and see if that's the issue. I bet constructing the DOM and rendering it is your bottleneck.

Comment: However, I see a large bar originating from googletagmanager... Do you have third-party scripts getting injected from that?

Comment: What you can try is at least keeping an eye on the question you just posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Google Chrome v107. Updating to v108 fixed the issue immediately.